# How to pip install libraries (lomap specifically) in python with the print command still in python 2.7, so without parenthesis: print()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, printing, pip

When installing the lomap library using pip install, I get a syntax error concerning the print command, which is now a function in python-3.x. I am using python-3.7.4 in windows 10.

I have no clue how to solve this as I cannot access the library to remotely change the print command to the print function. Since I suspect that is the problem.

The only code used is:

```
pip install lomap
```

in cmd.

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\20172542\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n_o4jham\\lomap\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\20172542\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n_o4jham\\lomap\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\20172542\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_o4jham\lomap\
Complete output (6 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\20172542\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_o4jham\lomap\setup.py", line 23
    print '\n###\n# LOMAP has been installed to %s.\n# To run the examples, copy the contents of %s\n# to a writable directory.\n###\n' % (install_dir, exp_dir)
                                                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The easiest "workaround" I can think of is to use Python 2… or download the source, run `2to3` on it, fix any problems that prevent it from running on Python 3 and then install it locally. :|

Comment: Yeah, project is not tagged. It is build for python2 only I think.